# Water The Trees - Python Error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b''

Tags: python, error-handling

I am trying to input and value and convert it into an integer.
However, I am facing an error -

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: b''

My code is [here](https://pym.dev/p/359hu/).
Below is the part where I am envoutering the error.

```
def main():
    t = int(input())
    for _ in range(t):
        N = int(input())
        A = list(map(int, input().split()))
        out = solve(N, A)
        print(out)
```

The error I receive is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\main.py", line 60, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\main.py", line 51, in main
    t = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b''
```

This is a Code Forces [problem](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1661/C).

Am I tackling the problem in a correct way?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You create a variable "input" which shadows the function "input". Rename your variable.

Comment: What was your input ? This issue is sometimes seen when you are trying to convert an empty string into an int.